# How to always return a JSON array for single result in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

What is the easiest or anticipated way to always return a JSON array from a API controller in Ruby On Rails?

Let's say I've the following controller action:

```
def index
  render json: Entry.all.includes(:user).to_json(include: :user) if current_user.has_role?(:administrator)
  render json: Entry.find_by(user: current_user).to_json(include: :user)
end
```

A list of entries is returned. Sometimes the result is only one entry, so `to_json()` doesn't create a JSON array but a JSON object instead.

This complicates everything like API documentation and implementation in the clients, because we have to test for empty results, single results and array results.

How is it possible to always return a JSON array here?

Stack: Ruby 2.5.3; Rails 5.2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this

```
render json: Entry.find_by(user: current_user).to_json(include: :user)
```

to

```
render json: Entry.where(user: current_user).to_json(include: :user)
```

`find_by` returns an object, whereas `where` an `ActiveRecord::Relation`

Comment: Maybe he wants an array with just one element, if this is the case, he should use Entry.where(user: current_user).limit(1) that will generate the same query of Entry.find_by(user: current_user), but will return just one object in an ActiveRecord::Relation.

Comment: Thank you. I just forgot about that `find_by` only the first result.